# Using hashchange to show/hide divs. How can I disable a CSS transition when page is reloaded or direct link is used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the index page of a site, I have a 100vh div which contains a hero image as a background (`#hero`), and some text on top of it that lives inside the `#introcontainer` div.

I have it set up so that when you go to other pages via hashchanges, `#hero` transitions down to a height of 85px, and `#introcontainer` is hidden.  Everything is working great showing/hiding content using a switch function.

The problem is, when I refresh or go to the url with the hash directly, the hero image is briefly displayed and does it's 200ms transition down to its compressed size.  I'd like to prevent that if possible.

```
<script>
    function nav() {
    switch (window.location.hash) {
                case "#work":
                        document.getElementById("workblock").style.cssText = 'display: block;'
                        document.getElementById("workblock").className = ""
                        document.getElementById("aboutblock").style.cssText = 'display: none;'
                        document.getElementById("recentblock").style.cssText = 'display: none;'
                        document.getElementById("hero").style.cssText = 'height: 85px; transition: 200ms ease-in-out; cursor: auto;'
                        document.getElementById("introcontainer").style.cssText = 'visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;  transition: visibility 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;';

                        break;

                case "#about":
                        document.getElementById("aboutblock").className = ""
                        document.getElementById("aboutblock").style.cssText = 'display: block;'
                        document.getElementById("recentblock").style.cssText = 'display: none;'
                        document.getElementById("workblock").className = "offscreen"
                        document.getElementById("hero").style.cssText = 'height: 85px; transition: 200ms ease-in-out; cursor: auto;'
                        document.getElementById("introcontainer").style.cssText = 'visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;  transition: visibility 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;';
                        break;


                default:
                        document.getElementById("recentblock").style.cssText = 'display: block;'
                        document.getElementById("aboutblock").className = "offscreen"
                        document.getElementById("workblock").className = "offscreen"
                        document.getElementById("hero").style.cssText = 'height: 100vh; cursor: auto;'
                        document.getElementById("introcontainer").style.cssText = 'visibility: visible; opacity: 1;  transition: visibility 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;';

        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        nav();

    $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(){
        nav();
       });
    }); //doc ready
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the `transition` css style rule in `ready` callback.

Try this:

```html
<script>
function nav(isHashChange) {
    switch (window.location.hash) {
        case "#work":
            document.getElementById("workblock").style.cssText = 'display: block;'
            document.getElementById("workblock").className = ""
            document.getElementById("aboutblock").style.cssText = 'display: none;'
            document.getElementById("recentblock").style.cssText = 'display: none;'
            document.getElementById("hero").style.cssText = 'height: 85px; transition: 200ms ease-in-out; cursor: auto;'

            document.getElementById("introcontainer").style.cssText = isHashChange
                ? 'visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;  transition: visibility 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;'
                : 'visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;';

            break;

        case "#about":
            document.getElementById("aboutblock").className = ""
            document.getElementById("aboutblock").style.cssText = 'display: block;'
            document.getElementById("recentblock").style.cssText = 'display: none;'
            document.getElementById("workblock").className = "offscreen"
            document.getElementById("hero").style.cssText = 'height: 85px; transition: 200ms ease-in-out; cursor: auto;'
            document.getElementById("introcontainer").style.cssText = isHashChange
                ? 'visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;  transition: visibility 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;'
                : 'visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;';
            break;


        default:
            document.getElementById("recentblock").style.cssText = 'display: block;'
            document.getElementById("aboutblock").className = "offscreen"
            document.getElementById("workblock").className = "offscreen"
            document.getElementById("hero").style.cssText = 'height: 100vh; cursor: auto;'
            document.getElementById("introcontainer").style.cssText = isHashChange 
                ? 'visibility: visible; opacity: 1;  transition: visibility 200ms, opacity 200ms linear;'
                : 'visibility: visible; opacity: 1;';

        }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    nav(false);

    $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(){
        nav(true);
    });
}); //doc ready
</script>
```

Comment: Ahh. That makes sense.  Where should it go?  In a click function of the divs that are shown/hidden?

Comment: This is great! Thanks.

At first it didn't work. Even making it's own function as a click event separate from the switch didn't work. THEN I remembered I had     

`* {
    -webkit-transition:all 200ms ease;
         -moz-transition:all 200ms ease;
               -o-transition:all 200ms ease;
                     transition:all 200ms ease;

}`

in my CSS! Not doing that again.